# How to convert a single number into Private key in python

Tags: python

[image]

https://brainwalletx.github.io/#converter,
5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAnchuDf

This private key  is generated from 1

If i do this other way on this same site, It gives me different result

[image]
I want a formula to convert This 1 into this private key(5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAnchuDf) in python
Anyone knows formula or python code to do this ?

Comment: You can go to the chapter 4 but doing the whole thing from the start would be best https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) Python library (I am the author)

```
>>> from cryptotools import PrivateKey
>>> i = 1
>>> prv = PrivateKey(i.to_bytes(32, ‘big’))
>>> prv.wif()
‘5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAnchuDf‘
```

Comment: Thanks , Exactly what i needed

Comment: This code gets compressed key, Is there anyway to get Uncompressed from same way.
Thanks

Comment: The code above is uncompressed. For compressed use `prv.wif(compressed=True)`

Comment: It gives me different result for compressed key 
for example [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydbhn.png
This key is 769
But the script give me this key 
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/48GFY.png

What am i doing wrong 
What change do i have to do to get KwDiBf89QgGbjEhKnhXJuH7LrciVrZi3qYjgd9M7rFU74sHUHy8S , from i = 769

Comment: I think the brainwallet site is padding to 33 bytes in the last screenshot so replace 32 with 33

Answer (score 1):

> **If i do this other way on this same site, It gives me different result**

Try entering `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` and selecting `Hex` at the top and `Base58check` at the bottom.

[image: brainwallet webpage]

---

> **I want a formula to convert This 1 into this private key (5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAnchuDf) in python**

https://www.google.com/search?q=python+base58check leads to https://pypi.org/project/base58check/ and many others.

Note that these libraries require that your value 1 be expressed as a byte array, not as a single decimal integer.

---

Remember that what you are seeing is not *conversion of a single number into a private key* but simply the same number presented in two different representations. That is, two different encodings. Note also that encoding is not encryption.

- 1 is the same number as 0x01 even though the latter is encoded as hexadecimal.
- 1 is the same number as 5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAnchuDf even though the latter is encoded as Base58check.

Comment: Any idea how can i convert 1 into the byte array and then convert that bye array into the privatekey 5HpHag...... I want to do all of these in python

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it "from scratch" with just hashlib, binascii and base58 modules:

```
import hashlib, binascii, base58

pkeyhash = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"

pkeyvbytes = "80"+pkeyhash

firsthash = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(pkeyvbytes)).hexdigest()

secondhash = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(firsthash)).hexdigest()

createkey = pkeyvbytes+secondhash[:8]

WIF = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(createkey))

print(WIF)

>>> 5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAnchuDf
```